# Error in Python's os.walk?

Tags: python

The `os.walk` documentation (http://docs.python.org/library/os.html?    highlight=os.walk#os.walk), says I can skip traversing unwanted directories by removing them from the dir list. The explicit example from the docs:

```
import os
from os.path import join, getsize
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('python/Lib/email'):
    print root, "consumes",
    print sum(getsize(join(root, name)) for name in files),
    print "bytes in", len(files), "non-directory files"
    if 'CVS' in dirs:
        dirs.remove('CVS')  # don't visit CVS directories
```

I see different behavior (using ActivePython 2.6.2). Namely for the code:

```
>>> for root,dirs,files in os.walk(baseline):
...     if root.endswith(baseline):
...             for d in dirs:
...                     print "DIR: %s" % d
...                     if not d.startswith("keep_"):
...                             print "Removing %s\\%s" % (root,d)
...                             dirs.remove(d)
...
...     print "ROOT: %s" % root
...
```

I get the output:

```
DIR: two
Removing: two
DIR: thr33
Removing: thr33
DIR: keep_me
DIR: keep_me_too
DIR: keep_all_of_us
ROOT: \\mach\dirs
ROOT: \\mach\dirs\ONE
ROOT: \\mach\dirs\ONE\FurtherRubbish
ROOT: \\mach\dirs\ONE\FurtherRubbish\blah
ROOT: \\mach\dirs\ONE\FurtherRubbish\blah\Extracted
ROOT: \\mach\dirs\ONE\FurtherRubbish\blah2\Extracted\Stuff_1
...
```

WTF? Why wasn't `\\mach\dirs\ONE` removed? It clearly doesn't start with "keep_".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you're modifying the list `dirs` while iterating over it. `ONE` was just skipped and never gets looked at. Compare:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> for i in a:
    if i > 1:
        a.remove(i)


>>> a
[1, 3]
```

Comment: What he said. Notice in the example that they're modifying the `dirs` list BEFORE they iterate over it.

Comment: @jathanism: they don't iterate over `dirs` at all ;)

Comment: Well not in the example code, no. But it's assumed that one would, was more my point.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't removing it from the `dirs` list. If you were, you'd see your "Removing" print out, wouldn't you?

Change `for d in dirs` to `for d in list(dirs)` to safely remove items from the `dirs` list while iterating over it.

Or you could just write:

```
dirs[:] = [d for d in dirs if not d.startswith("keep_")]
```

Comment: Your first suggestion, using `list(dirs)` worked, but the list comprehension did not affect any change.

Comment: @Mike: because `os.walk` references original list, in order for list comprehension to work you need to do: `dirs[:] = [d for d in dirs if not d.startswith("keep_")]`